# Left margin grows while typing

Tags: buffers, margins

My buffer slips to the right while editing a file. Whenever I press a button, left margin area grows one character. This isn't happening for all files. My buffer normally looks like this:

```
line with text
another line with text
```

After I push a buttons, the screen slips to the right, left margin area grows and the buffer looks like this:

```
<this area got wider> line with text
<this area got wider> another line with text
```

This problem did not occur for all files; but it isn't resolved with restarting the Emacs.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`) and open up one of the files for which you have the problem.  Do you still have the problem?  If so, explain in more detail what is happening (more than "I push some buttons").  If the problem goes away, something in your init file is causing the issue.  You will need to bisect your init file recursively to identify the source.

Comment: It has gone when I open without init file. It seems the problem is the `git-gutter`. I found it is a known compatibility issue with `linum-mode` in Emacs 26.1. Everything has fixed when I use `display-line-numbers-mode` as suggested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great!  Can you expand on your comment as an answer post and then accept your own answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem is the `git-gutter`. I've searched and found it is a known compatibility [issue](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-gutter/issues/156) with `linum-mode` in Emacs 26.1. Everything has fixed when I use `display-line-numbers-mode` as suggested.

Comment: FYI: You can accept your own answer (anytime).

Comment: I will accept it tomorrow. The site doesn't allow me to accept my own answer before two days.